# She can/might get a job as a teacher?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

We were asked a question in an exam, [from *Grammarway* 4](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/5561032/page:20/). The question was:

> She ... get a job as a teacher. She loves children.

I prefered to use "can" because I thought that was possibility but teacher told us that "might" was the right answer.

Comment: Is this in a [formal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/can-or-may) context? Your instructor appears to be following a non-existent (but widely believed) rule.

Comment: He got the questions from "Grammar way 4"

Comment: Revision 4 units 1-12: [She ____ get a job as a teacher. She loves children](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/5561032/page:20/) Not the period/full stop usage)

Comment: I meant to say *Note the period/full stop.

Comment: Did you understand where the problem lied? Did Williams's answer help? Then everything is well in the world again :)

Comment: Modal verbs can be confusing at times but everything's good now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of word here relates to the second part of the sentence:  if it was "can", you would be saying

"Because she loves children, she is able to get a job as a teacher."

This isn't true:  the **requirement** for getting a job as a teacher is having the relevant qualifications, not loving children.

If it's "might", you would be saying

"Because she loves children, she may **choose** to get a job as a teacher."

This makes more sense - presumably she has a choice of jobs (and is qualified to be a teacher), and she may choose the teacher job because she would enjoy it, **because of** her love of children

Comment: The question was multiple-choice and he now says that both "can" and "both" will be accepted as right answers.

Comment: @MertBaşaran (1) Should you comment read "both 'can' and '**might**'"  - not "and 'both'"?  (2) Did the original question really have only a comma between the words "teacher" & "she" - because that would be very poor English! - or have you missed something out?

Comment: I think the comma's ok, isn't it?  Informal, perhaps, but perfectly acceptable, especially if it's spoken.

Comment: @MertBaşaran i think "can" is acceptable (it's not ungrammatical), but "might" is a better choice.  Your teacher relaxing the question doesn't change that.

Comment: @TrevorD see the original question which I cited in the comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks.  It really would help Op could copy the original question correctly!!!

Comment: @TrevorD Sorry for the punctuation and spelling mistake. It should have been "both 'might' and 'can". I also edited my post.